# Memory allocation of static data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-management, static

I have a service and I registered this dependency by autofac  in asp.net mvc5 framework.

```
public partial class EBayApiService : IEBayApiService
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly GlobalSettingsForEBay _globalSetting;
    private static ApiContext _context;
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public EBayApiService(GlobalSettingsForEBay globalSetting)
    {
        this._globalSetting = globalSetting;
        _context = GetApiContext();
    }

     static ApiContext GetApiContext()
    {
        //apiContext is a singleton,
        //to avoid duplicate configuration reading
        if (_context != null)
        {
            return _context;
        }
        else
        {
            _context = new ApiContext();
            return _context;
        }

        public CategoryTypeCollection GetAllEBayParentCategories(ApiContext context)
       {
           //here I play with _context.
       }

  }
```

For first time request from browser _context is null and it collect data. After that in every request it is not null.

Now my question is when it become null again? Or it take data only once in its whole life cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It take data only once in its life cycle unless you restart the IIS. If you restart the IIS than `_context` will be `null` again as `_context` is static type.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be null every page load in first (page "PostBack").

Comment: It is null first time when page load. After that it is not null in every page load.

Comment: yes, you can make sure by print statement inside null condition and try reload page many time by button or any thing